# How to upload a zip folder in AWS lambda (python) without storing in S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

How to upload a zip folder in AWS lambda functions (python) without storing in S3. I need to upload the python code written by me normally including all python libraries in order to run the program.

Comment: Zip up the code and dependencies, then use the awscli to deploy: aws lambda update-function-code ...

Comment: In order to use aws cli command we must have the access of aws lambda locally. ie, through terminal we need to do. How it will be in the case of AWS Console, if we consider the python packages to be just uploaded then just testing

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "we must have the access of aws lambda locally" but to upload a ZIP file to AWS Lambda, you only need the awscli (or you could, of course, use the AWS Console to upload it). Is your issue "how do I upload my code that's in a ZIP file to AWS Lambda?" or is it "I have uploaded my code, it has Python dependencies and it doesn't work"?

Comment: Yes, exactly I have uploaded my code, it has Python dependencies and it doesn't work. I got an error "the remote endpoint could not be called, or the response it returned was invalid"

Comment: There's not enough information here. Does your Lambda function actually execute (you can see this in CloudWatch Logs for the Lambda function)? What code is your function calling that results in the error message that you've shown us.

Comment: I edited and added the code segment that I am using AWS Lambda function. Here there is urllib3 python package. In order to upload as a zip folder, along with the packages and code uploaded. Uploaded successfully but it is showing an error "The remote endpoint could not be called, or the response it returned was invalid." No request is working properly.

Comment: 1) confirm did you installed package in the folder by pip command like pip install urllib3 -t . 2) Check the python is working fine from local machine 3) confirm the lambda is in private subnet?

Comment: yes, I installed using pip install urllib3 -t, python is working fine. After including this code only AWS lambda is showing the error (The remote endpoint could not be called, or the response it returned was invalid." )

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license).  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-route-for-a-dissociation-request).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to do this from AWS Console?
If yes then you simply have to select "Upload a .ZIP file" option in the "Code entry type" dropdown while creating the Lambda

That dropdown has 3 options as follows

1. Edit code inline
2. Upload a .ZIP file
3. Upload a file from Amazon S3

Comment: Ok. We can choose the Upload a .zip folder. But when I test, I am getting an error "the remote endpoint could not be called, or the response it returned was invalid" . This is because, the python dependencies that I upload along with zip folder cannot be used by the python code.

Answer (score 0):

select "Upload a .ZIP file" option from "Code entry type". then you need to change the Handler . for python code you will use  "main/lambda_handler".